# Total registros por dia nos ultimos 30 dias

Tags: php, mysql

Galera,

Acabei de fazer essa consulta, funciona muito bem até o dia de hoje(dia 20) menos 19, só que eu preciso que mostre os ultimos 30 dias.

**Assim funciona**

```
SELECT ID, DAY( created_at ) AS DIA, SUM( 1 ) AS HORAS
FROM registration
WHERE created_at
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE( ) -19
AND CURRENT_DATE( ) 
GROUP BY DAY( created_at ) 
ORDER BY DAY( created_at )
```

**Assim retorna a quantidade tudo errado**

```
SELECT ID, DAY( created_at ) AS DIA, SUM( 1 ) AS HORAS
FROM registration
WHERE created_at
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE( ) -30
AND CURRENT_DATE( ) 
GROUP BY DAY( created_at ) 
ORDER BY DAY( created_at )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, verifica se este SQL funciona:

```
SELECT ID, DAY( created_at ) AS DIA, SUM( 1 ) AS HORAS
FROM registration
WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY DAY( created_at ) 
ORDER BY DAY( created_at )
```

Comment: Rhadamez, perfeito! obrigado! Para colocar o dia e mês concatenado poderia me ajudar? Eu fiz assim mas ele soma -> DAY( created_at ) +  '/' + MONTH( created_at ) AS DIA

Comment: Consegui assim DATE_FORMAT( created_at,  '%m-%d' ) AS DATA

Comment: Show de bola, olha se esta formatação funciona: `SELECT ID, DAY( date_format(created_at, '%Y/%m') ) AS DIA, SUM( 1 ) AS HORAS
FROM registration
WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY DAY( created_at ) 
ORDER BY DAY( created_at )`

Comment: Ok, Resolvido! Obrigado

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu, abraço.